# apache ant: responding to prompt for password

Tags: java, ant

I am using ant to deploy an app to a Glassfish application server which requires a admin user/password for login. Could you explain how to provide password from ant build.xml itself without manual intervention?

(I understand hardcoding password is not recommended but please ignore it for this question)

Comment: The ant task should allow you to provide the password (or a password file) as an attribute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Ant `<input>` task can read a password form the user, or skip it if a property already exists.  from its docs:

```
<input
    message="Please enter db-username:"
    addproperty="db.user"
    defaultvalue="Scott-Tiger"
/>
```

If the property db.user already exists, this does nothing. if not, it prompts the user for a user name, and sets the db.user property to it.  If the user just types a return, it uses the default. if you're doing this from an IDE, check with its docs to set the right input handler.  For passwords, use `<handler type="secure"/>` as an inner element.

Now, you want to store the password in a separate file.  That's not a great idea, but people do it.  So, use the `<property>` task:

```
<property name="db.password" value="CompletelyInsecure"/> <!-- or -->
<property file="db.properties"/> <!-- Where db.properties contains the db codes. -->
```

For your situation, use both approaches.  I'd use a properties file, and then the `<input>` task.

To see how complex this can get, the Maven build system suggests people encrypt all password data and that they store the decryption key on a memory stick they keep with them.